# How to explicitly write out the conditional expectation of the expected absorption time in first step analysis of a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

A Markov chain $X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ has the transition probability matrix

$$P=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \alpha & \beta & \gamma \\
        0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

where the first row corresponds to $X_n = 0$ and the second row $X_n = 1$, and third row corresponds to $X_n = 2$.

We define $T = \min\{n\geq0: X_n=0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ X_n = 2\}$

I would like to find $v= E[T|X_0=1]$.

This question appears in the textbook Stochastic Modeling by Pinksy, and their explanation is: **"Weighting these contingencies by their respective probabilities, we obtain for $v$"**:

$$
v = 1+\alpha\cdot (0)+\beta\cdot (v)+\gamma\cdot (0) = 1+\beta v
$$

My question is two-fold:

1) What is the explicit notation for what is going on above? When they "weight" the probabilities, are they doing $E[T|X_0=1] = \sum_{k=0}^2 E[T|X_0=1, X_1=k]$?

2) What is a good way to see why there is the $1$ added above? I know the usual explanation is that the absorption time $T$ is always at least $1$, but how does it come out in the math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation should be

$
\begin{align*}
E(T\mid X_0=1)&=\sum_{k=0}^2 E(T\mid X_0=1,X_1=k)P(X_1=k\mid X_0=1) \\
&=E(T\mid X_0=1,X_1=0)\alpha+E(T\mid X_0=1,X_1=1)\beta+E(T\mid X_0=1,X_1=2)\gamma.
\end{align*}
$

The first and last expectations on the right become $1$ since we have hit $\{0,2\}$ in one time step. For the second expectation on the right, think of $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ as a new Markov chain starting at $1$. The transition probabilities from $X_1$ to $X_2$ to $X_3$ (and so on) do not depend on the original starting point $X_0$, but only on the new starting point $X_1$. Since $X_1$ is still $1$, the new Markov chain $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$ can be thought of as restarting original one $\{X_0,X_1,\dots\}$ and so $E(T\mid X_0=1,X_1=1)=1+E(T\mid X_0=1)$. The $1$ on the right is due to the fact that we have still expended one time unit to 'reset' our Markov chain. Putting everything together gives $$E(T\mid X_0=1)=1\alpha+(1+E(T\mid X_0=1))\beta+1\gamma=1+E(T\mid X_0=1)\beta.$$

Comment: awesome thanks, this is a very clear explanation!